# Mapped pinned host memory bandwidth when non-coalesced-ly accessed from the GPU kernel

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, pci-e

Assume that there's a large `int` array inside the host memory to which threads of a kernel read or write and cannot be held inside GPU global memory. When accesses to the elements of the array is coalesced, we can expect burst read/writes from/to the host memory which gets close to the theoretical bandwidth of the PCI-Express lanes. But how much will the bandwidth be compared to the theoretical maximum bandwidth when the read or writes are totally sporadic (non-coalesced)?

Based on below picture from [here](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/pci-express-tlp-pcie-primer-tutorial-guide-1), for every write transaction there should be a 128-bits long packet. But it assumes 32-bit addressing (considering UVA requires 64-bit machines) and 4 bytes as the data size. If these assumptions are true, one can expect around one-fourth of maximum bandwidth for writes and one-seventh for reads. Am I correct? Are these assumptions true?

[image]

### **Edit**

I designed and performed a test for above question with an `uint` array. The bandwidth I got was around 480 MB/s for both heavy sporadic reads and heavy sporadic writes on a PCI-Express link with about 6.6 GB/s bandwidth, showing 13 to 14 times slow down. How can it be explained?

Comment: I think its likely that the slowdown can be explained readily with a PCIE analyzer.  The answer is likely that the underlying packet organization is not what the question assumes, or that there are other intervening transactions/packets that have not been accounted for.  The [bandwidth to a single memory partition on a modern Intel CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/52213/Intel-Core-i7-2600-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz) exceeds the bandwidths being discussed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only NVIDIA knows for sure - it might have to do with host memory only being accessible from one of the memory partitions - but that is a known performance limitation with mapped pinned memory.  From p127-128 of [The CUDA Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321809467): "It is important that mapped pinned memory be accessed with coalesced memory transactions (Section 5.2.9). The performance penalty for uncoalesced memory transactions ranges from 6x to 2x.  But even on SM 2.x and later GPUs, whose caches were supposed to make coalescing an obsolete consideration, the penalty is significant."

Sounds like the penalty is even higher on more recent hardware.